# Get current tint for Desktop Tinting in macOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: macos, colors, custom-controls, nscolor, macos-mojave

I am trying to read the current value of the tint applied in macOS 10.14 Mojave, and subscribe to updates. The color will update with the background image when you are in Dark mode and the Graphite color accent is not selected.

I would expect to be able to read it from `NSColor.windowBackgroundColor`, but the stored color does not seem to change, despite changes to what is on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the behind-window tint that is applied to the window background, there doesn't seem to be a way to get that since it's location dependent: drag your window over a light and a dark background and see how that shines through as you move your window. The actual color is computed by the window compositing system.

Since you refer the "stored color", if you mean the CGColor and notice that this doesn't change as you switch from light to dark mode or vice versa, you may need to explicitly set the appearance first:

```
let saved = NSAppearance.current()
NSAppearance.setCurrent(someView.effectiveAppearance)

// Here you can access the "true" colors (minus vibrancy/compositing effects):
let cgColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor.cgColor

NSAppearance.setCurrent(saved)
```

This is necessary when working outside a `drawRect:` method (which automatically sets up the current appearance for you).